# Issue with Spring Data Jpa meta-models

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, metamodel

I was reading through this tutorial: [Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl)
, trying to learn about specifications to build a dynamic filtering system, and how I can implement it in my Maven java springboot project using Spring data JPA, of course, reading and watching other tutorials, I realized that most use the untype-safe way to get the Entity fields(calling entitie attributes as a String name), this was a major concern for me until I discovered the Meta Model thingy, and it provided my with the promise of type-safety and early error detection.

Now, the issue is that, I cant figure out how to get Meta Model to work, at first I was under the impression that it should be generated automatically by spring data jpa, then I discovered after further research into the matter that nope, it requires a dependecy, this depenedency to be precise: `hibernate-jpamodelgen` which I added into my `pom.xml` from here [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-jpamodelgen/6.2.6.Final), but still it did not work, seems like adding the dependency alone does not work.

After further research, I found a lot of tutorials, but none of them seem to work, a lot of tutorials on Meta Model seem to just throw this most of the time but never show me how to add the folder to the classpath

> "If you use maven, the generated metamodel classes are stored in the
> target/generated-classes folder. So you need to add this folder to the
> classpath definition in your IDE."

I also found this tutorial [Hibernate Tips: How to automatically add Metamodel classes to your project
By Thorben Janssen](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-automatically-add-metamodel-classes-project/) but he uses a completly different way.

Another tutorial suggested to add a plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But none seem to be working for me, what should I do.

This is the my full `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>monty.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>content</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>content</name>
    <description>This is a microservice for content service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>2.1.0</springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <apache-tika.version>2.8.0</apache-tika.version>
        <hibernate-jpamodelgen.version>6.2.6.Final</hibernate-jpamodelgen.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- CORE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The hibernate validator for extra validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The DTO Mapper library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The swagger library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The file analysis service -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-tika.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-tika.version}</version>
        </dependency>

            <!-- This library allows to generate the metamodels for entities -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-jpamodelgen.version}</version>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.26</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>



                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Those are just JPA metamodels. Spring Data JPA is just a wrapper. That being said, it is an annotation processor which should be automatically picked up. So adding it to your dependencies should be enough. If that doesn't trigger it you can modify the `maven-compiler-plugin` to include the annotation processor. Also the tutorial you found is for adding the `generated-classes` dir as a source dir, which was a follow up for this https://thorben-janssen.com/static-metamodel/ (the metamodel question)

Comment: @M.Deinum I already have the maven-compiler-plugin added since I am using it for lombok and mapstruct. But what should I add to maven-compiler-plugin, since, I did try to add the jpamodelgen to the <path></path> but I got the error "Cannot find 'dependency' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.DependencyCoordinate"

Comment: If you are also using Lombok you are a bit in a pickle... Please add your pom instead of snippets, because you seem to have leftovers off all sorts of tries which are fighting with each other. Next to that Lombok and the metamodel generateor might fight each other.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added my pom.xml to my question.

Comment: Adding what you have as a dependency to the compiler plugin should work. You might need an explicit version, if you don't need an explicit version I suggest to use `hibernate.version` instead of declaring your own (that way it aligns with the Hibernate version that Spring Boot pulls in.

Comment: @M.Deinum What do you mean, and could this be the reason for the issue I am facing.

Comment: I mean exactly as I explain? Add the path to the compiler plugin and align the version (and ditch the `maven-processor-plugin`).

Comment: @M.Deinum I managed to make it work, without having to drop the maven-compiler-plugin, apperently, when I was adding the jpamodelgen to the path in the annotationProcessorPath, I was not removing the <dependency>, which was causing the original error.

Comment: Where did I say you needed to drop the `maven-compiler-plugin`? I was referencing the `maven-processor-plugin`, which you had in your pom. Having both won't work afaik.

Comment: But my pom.xml does not have anything called `maven-processor-plugin`